# increase vm size for aptana

Tags: aptana-studio

how to increase initial and max vmarg for aptana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aptana is based on eclipse. So depending on your OS and installation path, you should be able to locate eclipse.ini. The vmargs should be put in that file. My file on OS X looks like this

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx_1.0.1.R35x_v20090707
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```